# Obtener listado de archivos con su tamaño

Tags: msdos

Buen día.

Intento realizar un comando MS-DOS, para poder listar los archivos de un directorio, pero requiero omitir ciertos tipos de archivos, ademas de que si es posible muestre solo el nombre, la ruta y fecha de ultima modificación, hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
dir /s > listado.txt
```

Con este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que no me muestre los directorios (Folder 1, 2, 3 y 4), obviamente dentro de esos directorios existen más archivos, por lo que deberá mostrarlos también, ya sea en la misma linea o  en una nueva.
El resultado seria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que  quieres puedes hacerlo utilizan el parámetro /A:-D que excluye los directorios.

```
    dir /A:-D  /s
```

Con este comando tienes una lista como la que muestras  en tu ejemplo.

Por  otro lado si quieres tener los datos separados por `;`, por ejemplo,  puedes usar:

```
   for /R  %i in  (*.*) do  @echo %~dpi;%~nxi;%~zi;%~ti
```

Luego de /R puedes poner  el directorio que quieras. En el ejemplo de arriba asume el directorio actual.  El comando anterior te devuelve:

```
  <directorio>;<nombre de archivo>;<tamaño>;<fecha y  hora>
```

Puedes  redirigir  la salida a un archivo y ya tienes  los datos para que puedas leerlos o  importarlos como archivo separado por ";",

Comment: Muchas gracias, si lo muestra en consola pero si le agrego: for /R  %i in  (*.*) do  @echo %~dpi;%~nxi;%~zi;%~ti  > lista.txt, solo guarda la información del ultimo archivo.

Comment: Con gusto saber que pude apoyarte

Comment: Añade >> listado.txt